# Учу питон, как стоит решать задачи? Своим способом или привыкать писать более короткий(правильный) код?

Tags: python

Без подсказки не всегда понимаю, cтоит ли использовать определенную функцию, а сделаю все сложнее, длиннее, но по-своему, так, как я понимаю. Следует ли привыкать к более правильному решению или этот навык появиться с опытом?

Comment: А как можно привыкнуть к эталонному решению, если Вы его не знаете? Пишите код настолько хорошо, насколько позволяют Ваши текущие знания.

Comment: Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ, либо удалите вопрос вовсе.

Answer (score 5):

Я бы посоветовал совмещать: сперва решать с помощью уже изученного + мануалов, а потом, когда решил и все работает, смотреть эталонное решение, сравнивать, запоминать альтернативные подходы и более короткие способы. Так материал будет лучше усваиваться.

Answer (score 5):

Этот вопрос касается темы изучения языков программирования в общем, не только лишь одного Python.

Оттачивать нужно "самостоятельно", но стремиться к простоте. Хороший код - это "глупый" код.

Решение задач "по-своему" позволяет развивать умение мыслить и писать код самостоятельно: один вариант кода вытекает из другого.

Однако программирование - стезя, где категорически нельзя "вариться в своём бульоне". Для того, чтобы прогресс не стух, чтобы видеть другие пути применения фич языка, надо читать чужой код. Читать и думать: какие проблемы стояли перед автором, как он их решил, как можно было решить по-другому и в чем выгода, зачем используется вот эта штуковина, а зачем вот эта.

Соотвественно, брать на вооружение, применять, пробовать, решая задачи по-своему.

Answer (score 5):

Эталонное решение у вас вряд ли получится если вы совсем только изучаете что-то. И это нормально. Но вот изучать эталонные решения — стратегия верная.

На мой взгляд во время обучения стоит как можно больше пробовать. Пробуйте написать решение разными способами. Делайте для себя какие нибудь ограничения (без фанатизма), и потом уже изучайте эталонное решение, и смотрите как вы были далеко от него, и почему не дошли до него сами.

Таким образом у вас будет формироваться то самое мышление, которое необходимо для эталонного решения

Answer (score 4):

По-моему мнению самым главным было вовремя понять правило KISS(keep it simple stupid) , или по-другому просто не усложнять , если можно , не нужно засовывать повсеместно одни функции , их стоит добавлять когда это действительно необходимо , а сейчас советую писать код так , как можешь , потому что все нужные знания придут с опытом и ещё могу посоветовать сайт [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/) , он поможет вам оптимизировать ваш код